# Using imageoptimize plugin not showing field on entries

Tags: plugin-imageoptimize

In Craft CMS, I am using the imageoptimize plugin to optimize images. I have added field imageoptimize & in assets created volume added field in field layout but when I am adding entry it showing me the message 'OptimizedImages fields only work when added to an Asset Volume's layout.'.

I am using Craft CMS version 3.024 and ImageOptimize plugin version 1.4.38.
Why is the field not showing up?

Comment: `"but when i am adding entry"` The field is not supposed to work for entries, it will only work for assets

Comment: @RobinSchambach In front-end, we have to code for that to make it image optimized?

Comment: For the source sets and sizes yes

Comment: @RobinSchambach In front-end i have tried this code :- {% set optimizedImages = entry.myAssetField.one().optimizedImagesField %}
    <img src="{{ optimizedImages.src() }}"
         srcset="{{ optimizedImages.srcset() }}"
         sizes="100vw" />
It is not showing images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a [per the documentation](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-imageoptimize#using-the-optimized-images-field), the **Optimized Images** field should *only* be added to an Asset Volume's layout. You do not need to, and should not add that field to your Section field layouts.

Please verify for me that after doing so, when you double-click on an Asset, you see a display similar to this:

[image: Screenshot]

c.f.: https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-imageoptimize/issues/106

**Resolution:** This ended up just being some local config issues with Asset Volumes, and then getting rid of pending stuck Queue jobs. After that, away we go!